# How does SimpleWorkerRequest associate MIME types with extensions?

Tags: .net, cassini, mime-types, simpleworkerrequest

I was serving html referencing svg files in [Cassini](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx), and having problems since the mime type was not being sent properly. I ended up writing my own port of [Cassini](http://github.com/zippy1981/Cassini) that set the extension based on mime type.

After a good night of sleep I realized that there might be some sort of registry key or config file where I can configure custom mime types for [SimpleWorkerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.simpleworkerrequest.aspx), the .NET class that serves content through Casinni. However, I don't know what that is.

Comment: Don’t know if this might help but SysInternals [ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx ] will show you all the file I/O and registry I/O the Hosting Assembly is doing.  Plus Reflector may help with the System.Web.Hosting assemblies.

Comment: Zippy I presume. I will take a look at the MIME type issues tonight r.e. CassiniDev. Thanks for the reference point.

Comment: OK, I deleted my answer because when I added mime types to my test suite WebDev fails - i.e. `application/octet-stream` for svg. In CassiniDev I folded in your fixes and while not optimal, neither is the MS implementation so what can you do? Looks like a big switch is coming to cassinidev and falling through to a call to UrlMon in the default. (UrlMon identifies .svg as text/xml). Thanks for the headsup.

Comment: Hey - check http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=12506 for some info on your fix.

Comment: Justin, I just released a VS compatible build that you can use in debugging. Source is coming soon. http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/05/22/release-cassinidev-for-visual-studio-2008-a-drop-in.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you'll have to be responsible for identifying and then sending the proper MIME types via the response headers using [SimpleWorkerRequest.SendKnownResponseHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.simpleworkerrequest.sendknownresponseheader.aspx).

A basic implementation and discussion of this can be found on [this blog post](http://www.blogfor.net/2008/09/22/testing-http-handlers-and-modules-without-a-web-server/).

Now if you'd like to reimplement IIS' list of MIME types, IIS stores its own list in the metabase (and subsequent XML).  [A previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355883/iis6-serving-unregistered-mime-types) highlights how to access that list and where to pull it from.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-implement, or just want to copy the list, there is a list of mime types included with the default installation of the Neokernel Web Server (http://www.neokernel.com) and the server can be easily configured to support different or custom mime types by updating the list.